# Modify value of LinkedList in HashMap

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

I need to add a new Object to the LinkedList inside of my HashMap

I`ve tried saving the LinkedList in a temporary variable, add the video to this and then add the list to the map with the put method, but i have the same problem.

```
public void addVideo(String nameChannell, Video video)
{
    mappa.get(nameChannell).add(video);
}

public void printVideo()
{
    Iterator<String> itera=mappa.keySet().iterator();
    while(itera.hasNext())
    {
        String canale=itera.next();
        LinkedList<Video> lVideo=mappa.get(canale);

        System.out.println("\tCanale: "+canale);
        for(int i=0;i<lVideo.size();i++)
            System.out.println(lVideo.get(i).getNome());
    }
}
```

The main function for adding video to my hashmap is `addVideo`, but when i do it the video is added to all of my keys and not only to `nameChannel` key.
I thought the problem could be the `printVideo` function too but can`t handle this.

Comment: That means you're putting the exact same LinkedList object in the map for every key. Accessing linked list elements by index in a loop is very slow. Don't do that. In fact, you should almost never use a LinkedList. use an ArrayList. And make sure you create a new one for each key of the map.

Comment: I`ve tried like this, updating the linkedList

    LinkedList<Video> lVideo=mappa.get(nomeCanale);
    lVideo.add(video);
    mappa.put(nomeCanale, lVideo);

And still got the same problem

Comment: Again, read my comment. The problem is not with updating the list. The problem is in code you didn't post: you are putting the **same, unique** list in the map for all keys. Don't do that. Create a new list for every key of the map.

Comment: Can you please show how you initialize your map?

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't get this part but now it's all okay :)

Comment: By the wai, Samuel Philipp, the map is initialized with 
`mappa = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<Video>>();` 
in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your `addVideo` method should be like below as you are probably using the same `List` as the value as mentioned by `@JB Nizet`

```
public void addVideo(String nameChannell, Video video) {
 if(mappa.containsKey(nameChannell))
 {
   mappa.get(nameChannell).add(video);
 }
 else {
   List<Video> videos = new BakedArrayList();
   video.add(video);
   mappa.put(nameChannell, videos);
 }
}
```